# Convert UDP to TCP - Ngrok TCP => UDP

Tags: udp, tcp, ngrok

I'm in a hurry at the moment.

My Question is, is there a way to forward UDP to TCP port?
I need this for hosting a game server for my friends, I want to
host Counter-Strike server for example, but it uses UDP (User Datagram Protocol) for server port, but NGROK only supports TCP (Transmission Control Protocl) & HTTP (HyperText Transfer Protocol).

I tried this while ago..

```
ngrok tcp 127.0.0.1:27015
```

and as usually it will start :

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                       (Ctrl+C to quit)

Session Status                online
Account                       Soricy Infinitive (Plan: Free)
Version                       2.2.8
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:18833 -> 127.0.0.1:27015

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

But fails to connect to `0.tcp.ngrok.io:18833` in the game, and displays that there is no UDP configured on the server side.

Is there any way I could do this differently? UDP=>TCP?

Comment: The short answer is "No."  You'd have to write some kind of proxy handler for yourself to forward it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout [DatagramTunnneler (on github)](https://github.com/MarkoPaul0/DatagramTunneler). It is an open-source c++ program which simply listens to UDP traffic and forwards it to a TCP endpoint of your choice. On that TCP endpoint another instance of the DatagramTunneler publishes the UDP data back onto a UDP channel.
Disclaimer: I wrote that tool.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to copy the "raw" udp Payload and create a new TCP packet with the raw payload. But you need to set the same data of the other layer except the udp layer. Also: You need a clean configuration of the tcp layer.

Comment: Never mind, got myself a VPS and now I can host the server using Wine :)
If NGROK ever implements UDP support, I will try that too!